# Gene flow analysis with a single mitochondrial marker

Tags: genetics, population-genetics, biogeography

I am currently studying a mud snail genus called *Ecrobia*. Several species of this genus occur in both the Mediterranean and Black seas. Therefore, I would like to investigate whether there is:

1. Intraspecifc gene flow between the Mediterranean and Black sea populations
2. Interspecific gene flow between the Ecrobia spp. occurring in the same water body

Therefore, I have a couple of questions:

- Is it possible to perform a gene flow analysis with a single mitochondrial marker (COI)? If so, which program could I use to run the analysis?
- Ideally, how many individuals per population are required? If I don’t have enough individuals, is there a rigorous way of clustering populations?